# ImageView not visible on my device

Tags: android, imageview, visibility, invisible

i have an xml code for a layout for my fragment consisting of FrameLayout and RelativeLayouts, anyways I have an imageview which is visible inside a relative layout in my design on Android Studio,meaning that when I check my design there, everything is good, However, when I run my code, it is not visible and I don't know why, 
Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_profile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.doyousonder.android.drawer.drawer_view_profile">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/UserDetailsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_corners"
    android:layout_below="@id/indicator"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <com.doyousonder.android.utils.OpenSansBTextView
            android:id="@+id/UserDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <com.doyousonder.android.utils.OpenSansBTextView
            android:id="@+id/Background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/UserDetails"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/trolley_grey"/>

        <com.doyousonder.android.utils.OpenSansBTextView
            android:id="@+id/Education"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/UserDetails"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="240dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/trolley_grey"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/editProfileGrey"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/UserDetails"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="300dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrowDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/UserDetailsLayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_down" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first relative layout, try removing

```
android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
```

and add this

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Reason : the relative layout takes up the space for the imageview since you have hardcoded `layout_marginTop` attribute of relative layout